# No feedback from terminal

Tags: command-line

I'm really new to ubuntu and I'm having trouble understanding something regarding feedback from the terminal.

The course book says that there is supposed to be feedback from the terminal when you give the "which" utility the name of a command that doesn't exist in your search path.

However, when I purposely do that, absolutely nothing comes up. See here:
[no feedback at all from using commands that obviously don't do anything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc5Pf.png)

Does anyone know how I could get the terminal to give me feedback for errors?

Comment: If "which" doesn't return a path, it hasn't found a path to return.  See "man which" for return/exist status when using in a script.

Comment: Your course book might be pegged to a different version of `which`. On Fedora and openSUSE, which returns `no X in path...`

Answer (score 6):

`which` never did show error messages on command line. At least not on Debian version of Linux. Every system seems to have their own version of which (one of the reasons other commands are preferred) so maybe your course was referencing another operating system? For usage in scripts you can have 3 exit statuses:

```
EXIT STATUS
   0      if all specified commands are found and executable
   1      if  one  or  more  specified commands is nonexistent or not executable
   2      if an invalid option is specified
```

Use `type`,`whatis`, or `whereis`. All 3 will show it did not find what you asked for.

```
$ type aaa
bash: type: aaa: not found
$ whereis aaaa
aaaa:
$ whatis aaaa
aaaa: nothing appropriate.
```

and

```
type firefox
firefox is /usr/bin/firefox
$ whereis firefox
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /etc/firefox 
  /usr/share/man/man1/firefox.1.gz
$ whatis firefox
firefox (1)          - a free and open source web browser 
  from Mozilla
```

---

Here is a bit of [history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then) on which from our U&L.

Answer (score -1):

`which` will show only Linux commands "which" exist on the system you have just tried random characters there... not an existent command...

Here are examples:

```
$ echo $PATH # This is my default path.
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games      

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

--- So echo $PATH will show my default locations which are: `/usr/local/sbin` and `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/sbin` and.. etc..

When you use `which python` the terminal command is looking for command python in all the existing PATHs that you have in the system and shows you where it is.

This is useful because sometimes you might have a launcher/command that is not listed in your default PATH. THEREFORE YOUR TERMINAL WILL COME BACK WITH A REPLY LIKE `command not found`

You can also define your path manually:

```
export PATH="/home/mihai"  
/home/mihai# ls  
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
```

The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the 
PATH environment variable.

```
ls: command not found  
echo $PATH  
/home/mihai
```

Comment: Please make you answer more understandable.

Comment: @George Is this more understandable? I didn't change anything except for the formatting.